# Does Google Page Speed takes javascript into account?

Tags: javascript, performance, loading

My page is a list of items with one image per item. The whole list is in the html code, but all the items are hidden by default with "display:none" in the CSS file, and a javascript file permits to display them with pagination. If javascript is disabled then the whole list is displayed (potentially hidding the images with a message saying one should enable javascript to see the images, I have not decided yet).

This way a user with javascript enabled will not load all the images at once.

I read google took page loading speed into account.
My question is : will google think, seeing my big html code with tons of images, "it must be slow to load, I'm gonna give it a bad mark" or will google take into account the javascript file to see that it's in fact not slow at all ? Or maybe will it test the javascript and the noscript versions and calculate the average ?

Comment: You can test your site speed as perceived by Google with [Google Webmaster](https://www.google.com/webmasters/).

Comment: As far as I know (according to it's reports)  it only considers position (in head or body) and file size (compressed or not) of a JavaScript file.

Comment: WIlhelm Klopp : my site is not online yet, do you think this tool is how google will rate me in the end https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ ? If so then it seems to take javscript into account.

Comment: In order to speed the page up you could set the attribute defer="defer" of the script-tag to tell the html-parser that there is no document.write operation in it so do not execute it before everything has loaded.Otherweise a script might stop every following request before it's executed. Consider that this attribut can be ignored too by browsers